# .Net web service with oauth2 only responds with unauthorized_client (400)

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm trying to get a simple webservice to work with oauth2 Client Credentials but the service responds with unauthorized_client when trying to get the token, I have searched and tried all I can find but without success.
My intention is to have the service to respond with a token which the client the shall use to fetch data from the service.
I'm using .Net framework 4.8.

configuration

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    Provider = new OAuthAppProvider(),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

This is my validation method and when using a breakpoint I can see that the client-id and secret is validated, and that the program calls context.Validated().

```
     public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
     {
         string clientId;
         string clientSecret;           

         //first try to get the client details from the Authorization Basic header
         if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
         {
             //no details in the Authorization Header so try to find matching post values
             context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
         }

         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
         {
             context.SetError("client_not_authorized", "invalid client details");
             return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
         }

         if (clientId.Equals("ZYDPLLBWSK3MVQJSIYHB1OR2JXCY0X2C5UJ2QAR2MAAIT5Q") && clientSecret.Equals("my-secret-password"))
         {
             context.Validated();            
             return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
         }
         context.SetError("unauthorized_client", "unauthorized client");
         return Task.FromResult<object>(null);            
     }
```

I'm using Postman as test client

[Postman screen shot]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffUsf.png)

And as seen in the screen shot, the server responds with a 400 and no token.
I'm completely out of ideas and grasping for hints.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, I also needed to override GrantClientCredentials in my provider class. Kind of strange that I did not find any examples of this when I searched.

This is my provider class:

```
      public class OAuthAppProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
  {
      public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
      {
          //first try to get the client details from the Authorization Basic header
          if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out string clientId, out string clientSecret))
          {
              //no details in the Authorization Header so try to find matching post values
              context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
          }

          if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
          {
              context.SetError("client_not_authorized", "invalid client details");
              return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
          }
          
          if (ValidateClient(clientId, clientSecret))
          {
              context.Validated();            
              return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
          }
          context.SetError("unauthorized_client", "unauthorized client");
          return Task.FromResult<object>(null);            
      }

      private bool ValidateClient(string clientId, string clientSecret)
      {
          return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"].ToUpper() == clientId.ToString().ToUpper() && 
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"].ToUpper() == clientSecret.ToString().ToUpper();
      }

      public override async Task GrantClientCredentials(OAuthGrantClientCredentialsContext context)
      {
          var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
          claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("LoggedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
          await Task.Run(() => context.Validated(claimsIdentity));
      }
  }
```